# Let OS delete files

Tags: java

Is there a way in java to orphan inodes so that the os can clean them up?

My goal is to recursively delete a folder, but it doesn't matter when it's deleted, just that it is. Since deleting it in time takes a while and slows me down, I've been using `File.deleteOnExit()`, but that leaves the directory skeleton in place. Are there any solutions that can do this? This is currently what I do:

```
public static void markAllForDeletion(String folderName){
    String newName = folderName + " " + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    new File(folderName).renameTo(new File(newName));
    markBelow(new File(newName));
}

public static void markBelow(File folder){
    for(File file: folder.listFiles()){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            markBelow(file);
        } else {
            file.deleteOnExit();
        }
    }
    folder.deleteOnExit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the folder for deletion before marking any of the folder contents:

```
public static void markBelow(File folder){
    folder.deleteOnExit();
    for(File file: folder.listFiles()){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            markBelow(file);
        } else {
            file.deleteOnExit();
        }
    }
}
```

This is because the deletes from `deleteOnExit` take place in reverse order, as per [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--):

> Files (or directories) are deleted in the **reverse order** that they are registered.